# Using multiple dropdown toggles not working as expected

Tags: javascript, css

I am using the following to generate dropdown fields for a number of divs, but as it stands each generated toggle button will only open the first div's toggled content.

Here is what I'm using currently:

```css
.toggle {
  display: none;
}

.option {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.bio-title,
.bio-content {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transform: translateZ(0);
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

.bio-title {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 1em;
  display: block;
  color: #7A7572;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.bio-title:after,
.bio-title:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 1.25em;
  top: 1.25em;
  width: 2px;
  height: 0.75em;
  background-color: #7A7572;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

.bio-title:after {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.bio-content {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.bio-content p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0.5em 1em 1em;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.toggle:checked+.bio-title,
.toggle:checked+.bio-title+.bio-content {
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 6px #ddd, -3px 3px 6px #ddd;
}

.toggle:checked+.bio-title+.bio-content {
  max-height: 500px;
}

.toggle:checked+.bio-title:before {
  transform: rotate(90deg) !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="option">
  <input type="checkbox" id="toggle" class="toggle" />
  <label class="bio-title" for="toggle">
    Learn more
  </label>
  <div class="bio-content">
    <p>Content</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="option">
  <input type="checkbox" id="toggle" class="toggle" />
  <label class="bio-title" for="toggle">
    Learn more
  </label>
  <div class="bio-content">
    <p>Content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm open to using something like JavaScript but preferably would like to keep this CSS only. Is the latter even possible?

Comment: `id` should be unique, you are using the same id `toggle` twice. change the id of the second, and update its label to use the new id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to change the IDs.

```css
.toggle {
  display: none;
}

.option {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.bio-content {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: max-height 1s ease;
}

.toggle:checked+.bio-title+.bio-content {
  max-height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="option">
  <input type="checkbox" id="toggle" class="toggle" />
  <label class="bio-title" for="toggle">
    Learn more
  </label>
  <div class="bio-content">
    <p>Content</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="option">
  <input type="checkbox" id="toggle2" class="toggle" />
  <label class="bio-title" for="toggle2">
    Learn more
  </label>
  <div class="bio-content">
    <p>Content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

In your case - since nested DOM selectors are not *(yet)* supported - you could use a tiny JS snippet to achieve the same result, without IDs.

```js
function toggleTab(el) {
  // Get the first .toggle element of the parent
  const checkbox = el.parentNode.querySelector(':scope > .toggle');
  // Toggle the checked state
  checkbox.checked = !checkbox.checked;
}
```

```css
.toggle {
  display: none;
}

.option {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.bio-content {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: max-height 1s ease;
}

.toggle:checked+.bio-title+.bio-content {
  max-height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="option">
  <input type="checkbox" class="toggle" />
  <label class="bio-title" onclick="toggleTab(this)">
    Learn more
  </label>
  <div class="bio-content">
    <p>Content</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="option">
  <input type="checkbox" class="toggle" />
  <label class="bio-title" onclick="toggleTab(this)">
    Learn more
  </label>
  <div class="bio-content">
    <p>Content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This looks great, but I maybe didn't explain this as best I could. My problem is that I'm using software to generate these divs as-needed; so am unsure how to incorporate different divs with something like a WP plugin. I will probably mark this as solved, as it does solve how I explained it originally, then re-asking the question.

Comment: @codeforever I understand :) no worries. Updated my answer with a minimal JS solution.

Comment: you're amazing! I will give this a shot today :)

Comment: Update: Worked like a charm.